# Is there a convention for where to put Chef Code, in a cookbook that uses Packer?

Tags: chef-infra, packer

I am working with Packer, Chef, and Test Kitchen (using ServerSpec). I have Kitchen figured out; it tests my cookbook and I am happy. Now I am trying to run Packer in the same repository, in the root directory. [Most of the examples](https://www.packer.io/docs/provisioners/chef-solo.html) point to `[cookbooks]`, but the repo is a single cookbook with `metadata.rb` and the `Berksfile` in the root. The Packer `.json` file is also there.

Do I need to separate these directories? When I do the Packer run it does not find my Chef recipe and hangs forever. Abbreviated examples:

#### packer.json

```
...
"provisioners":
[
  {
    "type": "chef-solo",
    "cookbook_paths": ["./"],
    "run_list": ["cookbook-name::default"]
  }
]
```

#### metadata.rb

```
name 'cookbook-name'
version '0.0.1'

depends 'git', '~> 6.0.0'
```

#### recipes/default.rb

```
include_recipe 'git'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use something like `berks vendor` to write out the full cookbook folder and then aim Packer at that.